# using timers to allow for continuous text entry

Tags: python, timer

I am a beginner python programmer, and need help!

I want to allow the user to enter words over and over for 30 seconds. Very simply, something like this:

## do for 30 seconds:

```
InWord = Entry(exchangep2_page1_canvas, width=21, font=("Helvetica", 30, "bold"), relief=GROOVE, textvariable=GettheWord)

InWord.pack(side='left')
InWord.focus_set()
exchangep2_page1_canvas.create_window(500, 425, window=InWord, anchor = NW)

InWord.bind('<Return>', comp_s)

def comp_s(event):
    winsound.Beep(Freq, Dur)
    print (GettheWord.get())
    InWord.delete(0,END)
```

## end of repeated code here

BUT! I also want to display the timer and countdown each second!

Can you help? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: If my answer helps, please confirm it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime

n = datetime.datetime.now()

while 1:
    # your repeated code here
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = a - n
    if delta.seconds > 1:
        n = a
        print a
    else:
        continue
```